# Unable to take value from collection (using GetElementsByClassName)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show an output that gets its value from a collection.

Here is the code.
For `'schnapps'` which shows twice, I manage to get the output I want.
But for `'potato'` I am unable to show output.

```html
    <tr>
        <td>Schnapps Distillery</td>
        <td class='inputText schnapps'></td>
        <td>600 Farmers & Workers</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div class='inline'>
            <div class='inline potato'></div><img class='smallLogos'
                src='../images/potato.png' /> -->
            <div class='inline schnapps'></div><img class='smallLogos'
                src='../images/schnapps.png' />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

```
schnappsElement = document.getElementsByClassName("schnapps");
potatoElement = document.getElementsByClassName("potato");

    //schnapps
    for (i = 0; schnappsElement[i] != null; i++) {
        schnappsElement[i].innerHTML = Math.ceil((Number(farmInput.value) + Number(workInput.value)) / 600);
    }

    potatoElement.innerHTML = schnappsElement[0].value;
```

Both commands in JS are activated by a listener command I didn't include.
The command works because I get the right output for Schnapps.

What I want is for `potatoElement` to have (and show) the same value as `schnappsElement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `schnappsElement[0]` doesnt not have `.value()`. Use `.innerHTML` instead.

And also, `potatoElement` is an array - you need to use it as `potatoElement[0]`.

```
schnappsElement = document.getElementsByClassName("schnapps");
potatoElement = document.getElementsByClassName("potato");

    //schnapps
    for (i = 0; schnappsElement[i] != null; i++) {
        schnappsElement[i].innerHTML = Math.ceil((Number(farmInput.value) + Number(workInput.value)) / 600);
    }

    potatoElement[0].innerHTML = schnappsElement[0].innerHTML;
```

Or you could simply include them both in the Loop:

```
schnappsElement = document.getElementsByClassName("schnapps");
potatoElement = document.getElementsByClassName("potato");

    //schnapps
    for (i = 0; schnappsElement[i] != null; i++) {
        var value = Math.ceil((Number(farmInput.value) + Number(workInput.value)) / 600);
        schnappsElement[i].innerHTML = value;
        if (potatoElement[i]) { potatoElement[i].innerHTML = value }
    };
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, still getting a lot of confusion as to which element works with which methods